# Enviar correo a varias direcciones de email a la vez

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Estoy trabajando con GeneXus 15 - Java Web, y quiero saber si hay alguna forma de poder enviar correo a varias personas a la vez, ya sea colocando en una "caja de texto" los correos separados por comas (",") o algo parecido.

Debo indicar que sí he conseguido enviar correo, más solo a un email.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas el [tipo de datos `MailMessage`](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6925,MailMessage%20Data%20Type,), el `To` es una colección, por lo que puedes agregar más de una dirección (lo mismo aplica para el `CC` o `BCC`).

```
&mailRecipient = new()
&mailRecipient.Address = &email1 
&mailRecipient.Name = &name1
&mailMessage.To.Add(&mailRecipient) 

&mailRecipient = new()
&mailRecipient.Address = &email2
&mailRecipient.Name = &name2
&mailMessage.To.Add(&mailRecipient)
```

y luego lo puedes enviar por ejemplo usando el [tipo de datos `SMTPSession`](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6937,SMTPSession%20Data%20Type,).

Comment: Pero las direcciones de email ¿las puedo colocar en una sola caja de texto o tengo que agregar varias cajas de texto? por que se puede dar el caso en el que agregue más de 10 correos.

Comment: Puedes usar una sola caja de texto, separarlas con coma o punto-y-coma, pero luego las tienes que separar de a una para agregarlas al `MailMessage`. Para eso puedes usar las funciones `strsearch` y `substr`.

Comment: Lo probaré y te comento.